Getting Mail Tips from M365 using Graph
I am trying to retrieve Mail Tips from M365 (via Graph) using this url:
/users/{id|userPrincipalName}/getMailTips

The documentation says that the scope "Mail.Read" is required. I tried adding that scope to my application's list of scopes, and in the request for a token, but I'm getting http error 400.  It seems like Graph doesn't think that scope is valid. Is there something wrong with the documentation? What other scope might work there?
Note: I don't think there is anything wrong with my pre-existing code. I was previously asking for scopes "offline_access user.read Files.ReadWrite.All" and that works fine.

You can get the error 400, if you are missing the request body. The body must contain EmailAddresses (for which you want to retrieve mailTips) and MailTipsOptions
POST /v1.0/me/microsoft.graph.getMailTips
{
    "EmailAddresses": [
        "user_email@contoso.com",
        "group_email@contoso.com"
    ],
    "MailTipsOptions": "automaticReplies, customMailTip, deliveryRestriction, externalMemberCount, mailboxFullStatus, maxMessageSize, moderationStatus, recipientScope, recipientSuggestions, totalMemberCount"
}

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-getmailtips?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-body
Otherwise try to check the error message.

Thanks.  My original question was not quite accurate.  The error 400 is actually on my attempt to get the Graph token, when I request scope "Mail.Read".  The error I get in the response is "the user or administrator has not consented to use the application...".  I'm about as certain as I can be that my authentication request includes that scope, that the app has it configured, and that the user (me) granted permission.  If I remove that scope, I can get the Graph token, but then trying to get MailTips results in http 403.  All this used to work, seems like something changed.
